# Apagar um editText ao modificar outro

Tags: android, autocompletar, runtime

To iniciando meus estudos em Android agora, e estou fazendo alguns testes.

Tenho dois campos AutoComplitTextView, nos dois é mostrado um id e uma descrição.
X1 e X2(nomes fictícios).
A list do X2 é filtrada pela escolha do X1.
Tem Alguma forma de que, se o usuario apagar o id(mesmo que seja so um numero) do X1 o campo X2 seja limpo?

X1 = Ccusto X2 = Operação

Meu xml dos campos ta assim.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="C.Custo"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_ccusto"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_ccusto"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Operacão"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_operacao"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_operacao"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

To usando esse na minha Activity.

```
 acetCcusto.setAdapter(adapterCcusto);  
 acetOperacao.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if(!acetCcusto.getText().toString().equals("")){
          int cdEquipamento = util.getInt(tvEquip.getText().toString());
          int cdCcusto = util.getInt(acetCcusto.getText().toString());
          adapterOperacao = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CcBO.getArrayOperacao(cdCcusto));
          adapterOperacao = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, EOBO.getArrayCdOperacao(cdEquipamento));
          acetOperacao.setAdapter(adapterOperacao);

      }
    }
});
```

btnCcusto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick: ");
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                .title(R.string.title)
                .items(CcBO.getArrayCcusto())
                .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                        acetCcusto.setText(text.toString());
                        acetOperacao.setText("");
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
});
btnOperacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!acetCcusto.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            int cdCcusto = util.getInt(acetCcusto.getText().toString());
            cdOperacao = CcBO.getArrayOperacao(cdCcusto);
            if (cdOperacao!=null){
                adapterOperacao = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cdOperacao);
            }
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                    .title(R.string.title)
                    .items(CcBO.getArrayOperacao(cdCcusto))
                    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                            acetOperacao.setText(text.toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você vai precisar adicionar um `TextWatcher` no seu x1.

**Exemplo:**

```
edtx1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                edtx2.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Através dos três métodos presentes no `TextWatcher` você consegue monitorar antes de o edit receber o novo valor, quando ele receber e depois que ele recebeu.

Nesse caso você precisaria utilizar `afterTextChanged`, seria acionado após seu edit receber um novo valor, assim você limpa o x2.

**Obs:** Se você precisar atribuir um valor ao x1, e não quer que apague o valor do x2, você precisa retirar o `TextWatcher` antes de atribuir, e depois adicionar novamente.

Comment: Era isso mesmo.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Fala Edu,

Você pode verificar se o campo está vazio, e ai apagar o segundo campo, exemplo:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(campoX1)) {
    campoX2.setText("");
    return;
 }
```

Se o campo 1 estiver vazio, o segundo também ficará.

Abraços.

Comment: Entao leo eu pensei nessa ipotese, mas se eu colocar esse comando ele vai apagar o X2 assim que clicar no X1.
Eu quero que apague o X2 somente se o X1 for apagado.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta, da uma olhada, dessa forma você verifica se o campo está vazio

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.
mas o victor ja me deu o que eu tava procurando